# Одновременный запрос SQL из PHP

Tags: sql

Необходимо решить такую задачу.
Допустим, мы делаем

```
INSERT INTO example(name) VALUES (example_name_1);
```

Но при этом таблица example состоит еще из 1 столбца - id, который идет AUTO_INCRIMENT.

Мне надо получить ID записи с name=example_name_1, но проблема в том, что их в таблице может быть несколько. Как получить последний?

Comment: Посмотрите [это][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501464/how-to-get-the-id-of-inserted-row-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT max(id), name FROM example WHERE name = 'example_name_1'
group by name
```

Comment: А если между INSERT и SELECT другой пользователь базы сделает такой же INSERT, то мы получим не свой id

Comment: Для этого существуют транзакции.

Answer (score 1):

Коллизия решается использованием транзакций, а если быть точнее применением уровня изоляций транзакций.

Более подробно [прочитайте здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D3%F0%EE%E2%E5%ED%FC_%E8%E7%EE%EB%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%ED%EE%F1%F2%E8_%F2%F0%E0%ED%E7%E0%EA%F6%E8%E9) и выберите в зависимости от своего SQL нужный уровень изоляции транзакций.